# Run Process id not running when initiated from an end to end flow in robot framework

Tags: selenium, process, operating-system, robotframework

I am using Run Process and Run command to execute a windows based script. If I am running only the below code it works perfectly fine. But when I am running as an to end to end scenario, its not working running the script, please help.

Running Code:

```
***Setting***
Library     OperatingSystem
Library        Process

*** Test Cases ***
test
    
    Run Process     C:\\Automation\\TestData\\fileuploadscript.exe
    Run     C:\\Automation\\TestData\\ClickOpen.exe
```

But when it comes to end to end script same code is not working

```
pageDashboard.Review Label 
Click Button     //input[@id='btnUpload']
Run Process     C:\\Automation\\TestData\\fileuploadscript.exe
Run     C:\\Automation\\TestData\\ClickOpen.exe
```

Comment: Please define what do you mean by "it's not running" - the execution never goes to that line, or it starts but there's an error, or - something else?

Comment: Execution never goes to that line.

Comment: So what happens on the last ran line? What's in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture logs first to understand where it is failing...
${result} =     Run Process     ${program}  stderr=STDOUT   timeout=10s
Log to Console ${result}